# Rails 4.1 with unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn, ruby-on-rails-4.1

In rails 4 if I added the `unicorn` gem to gem file, unicorn would boot instead of `WEbrick`, but in 4.1 WEbrick is booting even though I have added unicorn gem to gem file (uncommented it)
what should I do?
P.S. I was unable to find anything useful from Google because 4.1 is new :(

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4.1 comes with Spring, which works like Unicorn by preloading Rails. [This](https://github.com/rails/spring) might help you along.

Comment: Ty for this, but I only wanted to use unicorn as the web server

Comment: What he's trying to say is that you neeed to config spring to run Unicorn. Im havin the same issue. Searching for solution...